# Using Titanium framework to create global array

Tags: javascript, android, multidimensional-array, global-variables, titanium-alloy

I have three js controller file and 1 lib

**app/lib/Client**

```
function Client(id,name,blc){
    this.id=id;
    this.name=name;
    this.blc=blc;
};
Client.prototype.getName = function(){
    return this.id+' '+this.name+' '+this.blc;
};
Client.prototype.withdraw = function(amount){
    if(amount<0) return -1;
    if(this.blc<amount) return -1;
    return this.blc-=amount;
};
Client.prototype.deposite = function(amount){
    if(amount<0) return -1;
    return this.blc+=amount; 
};

module.exports = Client;
```

**app/controller/addClient //this is where I want to add to global array**

```
var args = arguments[0] || {};
var Client = require('Client');
function doClick(e) {
    var user_id = $.id.getValue();
    var user_name = $.name.getValue();
    var user_blc =  $.Balance.getValue();
    if(user_id.length<=0 && user_name.length<=0 && user_blc.length<=0){
        alert('you entred an invalid information');
    }
    else{
        var c = new Client(user_id,user_name,user_blc);
        alert(c.getName()+' is add successfly');

        //note!!!!!
        //add a global array to save the data 

        $.id.setValue("");
        $.name.setValue("");
        $.Balance.setValue("");
    }
}
$.addClient.open();
```

**app/controller/allClient 
//this is where i want to use the data in Global app to make a listView**

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a "global array" use [Alloy.Globals](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Alloy-property-Globals)

If you want a collection of models, use [Backbone](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Backbone_Objects_without_Alloy)